# NoSuchElementException when trying to find element with valid xpath on Chrome and Edge

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, browser-automation

- I am testing https://www.policybazaar.com using selenium, testNG, java. I get the no such element error while trying to select a date from date picker on https://www.policybazaar.com/travel-insurance/student/ .
- While experimenting with xpath ( "//div[@data-time='1687458600000']"): I am properly detecting the element in browser. When used in code, I am getting the error.
- Relevant code:
  WebElement initialization

```java
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@data-time='1687458600000']")
    private WebElement endDay;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id=\"startdate\"]")
    private WebElement datePicker;
```

Method for choosing date (datepicker.click() works and datepicker appears on screen)

```java
public void chooseDate() throws InterruptedException {
        datePicker.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        endDay.click();
    }
```

Test method:

```java
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "testSelectDestination")
    public void testChooseDates() throws InterruptedException {
        policyBazaarPage.chooseDate();
    }
```

Part of Error Trace:

```
FAILED: tests.PolicyBazaarLandingTests.testChooseDates
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@data-time='1687458600000']"}
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=113.0.1774.57)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element
Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [a54fc9488a04affd75b9e7bfc894b05e, findElement {using=xpath, value=//div[@data-time='1687458600000']}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not noticed data-time changed at every refresh/launch, which caused the `NoSuchElementException`. Changing the xpath, to eg: `xpath = "//div[text()='12']"`,helped in easily selecting the desired date.

Answer (score 0):

The `NoSuchElementException` in Selenium is thrown when the WebDriver is unable to locate the Web element on the web page: maybe the date picker is not yet visible, or is loaded asynchronously.
An exact solution would depend on the specifics of the date picker's implementation.
But, for testing, try and modify your `chooseDate()` method to wait for the element to become visible:

```java
public void chooseDate() throws InterruptedException {
    datePicker.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement endDay = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@data-time='1687458600000']")));
    endDay.click();
}
```

Here, `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions` are used to create an explicit wait for the `endDay` element to become visible. Note that you'll need to import the `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions` classes:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

Also note that Selenium can only interact with *visible* elements. You can check if an element is visible using the `isDisplayed()` method.
And double-check your XPath.